# How do I resolve memory issues in minix3?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine, minix

For a class I have to run minix3 on virtualbox and make changes to the kernel. This is fine on my laptop. However, on my desktop, I am constantly running into issues with memory. For example, whenever I have to run 'make build' in the /usr/src directory to build the source code, I end up with the verify_grant: grant failed or something error in the do_safecopy.c, which I presume is an issue with memory. Weirdly enough, if a make build fails, and I try to run something else, I get a kernel panic.

Today, I also tried to give minix some more memory, and I got one of the make commands to run fine(the make services command in the /usr/src/releasetools director) but only once, and when I powered down the vm to come back and try again, same error with this verify_grant message. Oddly enough, when I use to run java programs on this ubuntu machine and I would use Runtime.exec() to spawn a new process, and would call for the process to be killed, it wouldn't do so and I would have to manually kill it from the terminal using the pid. I think these issues could be related but I am unsure.

Specs:

- Ubuntu 19.04
- Virtualbox 5.2
- AMD Ryzen 5 2600
- Gigabyte B450M Motherboard
- 16GB Memory (i forget the brand)
- Radeon RX580

I really appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Verify the configuration of the virtual machine you are using (RAM, disk, perhaps other configuration pieces).The physical machine as itself should be extravagantly over-resourced for Minix, that can't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling nested paging. In my case the compilation worked. But it will take ages. Still looking for better solution.